# How do I get List of Epic Names List from Jira Rest API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-agile, jira-rest-java-api

How do I get List of Epic Names List from Jira Rest API

I am able to fetch TaskName, Assignee, Strat Date ,End Date but I am not able to get EpicNames

I am using below API to fetch Backlogs details

```
 https://localhost/rest/api/latest/
 project in (Abc,Cde,FGH) & sprint in openSprints()

 https://localhost/rest/api/latest/
  project in (Abc,Cde,FGH) & issuetype != Epic & resolution = Unresolved &  (Sprint = 
EMPTY OR Sprint not in (openSprints())) & assignee != null"
```

But I am not able to get EpicName from jira API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps your particular situation, but you could try and create a filter that returns the data you need and then get the filter results using the API.